# Does NX use `package.json` file for cache key calculation?

Tags: caching, monorepo, nomachine-nx

I noticed that changes in the root's `package.json` doesn't burst the cache of my package even though the library is directly used there. The monorepo is generated using standard generators and no changes are made to inputs. The package itself is buildable and uses nx/esbuild executor.

Should i manually add `package.json` to inputs? Is it a correct behavior of nx?